# Magento Search not working in Firefox Browser

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, search-terms

I have a site in Magento 1.7.0.2 and when i search for products from site frontend using name or SKU, in firefox, the search doesnt return any results. But the same term fetches result in Chrome browser. How can I fix this bug which occurs in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific ? Technically there is no difference between Firefox and Chrome because the search is on the framework side and server side.
The only difference is the frontend side, the javascript. Do you have any JS error ?

Comment: I have this error in chrome console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined . In chrome everything works fine but only in firefox ther ] error occurs

Comment: I don't know how Firefox and Chrome react with JS errors, if they stop process or not but you have to fix this issue before to go any further with your main issue.